# Do these distributions of $X$ represent a reasonable model? (With $X$ being a random discrete variable)

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random discrete variable. Are the following suggested distributions of $X$ a resonable model?

$a)$ One time pulling a ball out of an urn with white and black balls, $X \in \{0,1\}$ representing the amount of white balls: **Bernoulli distribution**

$c)$ Out of $N$ fish, $M$ have been marked. Now one catches $k$ fish. $X$ represents the amount of marked, caught fish: **Hypergeometric distribution**

I have the following:

$a)$ True (because urns use bernoulli distribution)

$c)$ True because the description fits a hypergeometric distribution and it's a discrete probability distribution.

Are these answers correct or false?

Comment: looks good to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers were correct, i.e. Bernoulli distribution and Hypergeometric distribution